# Receiving managed package error - Cannot find respective method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, npsp

I am working with NPSP and their GE_GiftEntry components and am receiving a "Attempt to de-reference a null object". Because it is a managed package there is no stack trace. In dev tools I see the following request message, with which I get a failure. It says the method is getGiftView, but I am unable to find that in the GE_GiftEntryController class in their github repository.

```
{
   "actions":[
      {
         "id":"710;a",
         "descriptor":"aura://ApexActionController/ACTION$execute",
         "callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN",
         "params":{
            "namespace":"npsp",
            "classname":"GE_GiftEntryController",
            "method":"getGiftView",
            "params":{
               "dataImportId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "cacheable":false,
            "isContinuation":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Response from dev tools

```
{"actions":[{"id":"710;a","state":"ERROR","returnValue":{"cacheable":false},"error":[{"exceptionType":"System.NullPointerException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"Attempt to de-reference a null object","stackTrace":"(System Code)"}]}],"context":{"mode":"PROD","app":"one:one","pathPrefix":"","fwuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","mlr":1,"uad":1,"descriptorUids":{},"loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://one:one":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"globalValueProviders":[{"type":"$Global","values":{"eswConfigDeveloperName":{"writable":true,"defaultValue":""},"isVoiceOver":{"writable":true,"defaultValue":false},"setupAppContextId":{"writable":true,"defaultValue":""},"density":{"writable":true,"value":"VIEW_ONE"},"srcdoc":{"writable":false,"defaultValue":false},"appContextId":{"writable":true,"value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"dynamicTypeSize":{"writable":true,"defaultValue":""}}}],"enableAccessChecks":true,"dns":"c","ls":1,"lav":"54","ch":"https://static.lightning.force.com/cs201","mna":{"lightning":"interop"},"arse":1,"acaf":1,"services":["markup://force:initServiceSfdc","markup://lightning:configProvider","markup://force:salesforceScopedModuleResolver","markup://force:ldsEngineCreator","markup://instrumentation:locatorService"]},"perfSummary":{"version":"core","request":1240,"actions":{"710;a":{"total":1157,"db":10}},"actionsTotal":1157,"overhead":0}}
```

How can I proceed with debugging this issue?

Comment: Have you enabled/configured Gift Entry? https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Configure-Gift-Entry

Comment: Yes, we have. The Opportunity gets created, but the error prevents the process from finishing gracefully